# What is the domain and range of this composition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and  $f^{-1}:B\rightarrow A$

Let $G$ be an equivalence relation in $B$

Domain of $f^{-1}\circ G\circ f= A$?

Range of $f^{-1}\circ G\circ f \subseteq  B$ ?

Since $G$ is an equivalence relation

$f^{-1}\circ G\circ f=  f^{-1}\circ f $

I am kind of stumped on it

Comment: Recall that $G \circ f$ means: "apply" $f: A \to B$ and then $G$ which is an equiv rel on $B$. Thu, $G \circ f \subseteq A \times B$ that means that $\text {Dom}(G \circ f)$ is $A$. Now "add" $f^{-1} : B \to A$...

Comment: Could I do $f^{-1} o G \subseteq$ B X A and add f

Comment: See [Composition of relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations#Definition): we start from left with $f \subseteq A\times B$, then apply $G \subseteq B \times B$ and finally apply $f^{-1} \subseteq B\times A$. The domain is the "starting point" and thus it must be $A$. The range must be a subset of $A$, because the "end point" of $f^{-1}$ is in $A$.